# facebook android crashing

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

```
JSONObject json = null;
                            try {
                                json = Util.parseJson(fb.request("me"));
                            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

Above is the code within  **`onComplete()`** method.

I get response **"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=********"* which is perfect when I enter it in browser I receive json response but facebook sdk Util.class crashes below is the logcat error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.writeRequestHeaders(HttpEngine.java:625)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:771)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:270)
at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:211)
at com.facebook.android.Facebook.requestImpl(Facebook.java:790)
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:717)
    at com.example.check5.MainActivity$1$1.onComplete(MainActivity.java:112)
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.onSessionCallback(Facebook.java:331)
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.access$11(Facebook.java:312)
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook$1.call(Facebook.java:291)
    at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1316)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please let me know what is the problem.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you initialized the fb variable?

Comment: Facebook fb;  below MainActivity.class and  fb= new Facebook(App_Id); below     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: yes ..  fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"email","user_birthday","read_stream", "offline_access" }, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

Comment: Just in case, in other SDK's examples, they request "/me", with a forward slash. Chances are, that may have HttpEngine read the right response

Comment: still crashing at response = read(conn.getInputStream());

Comment: Its working on emulator but not on device.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("access_token", facebookManager.mFacebook.getAccessToken());
    b.putString("query", "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()");

    try {
        String myResult = Util.openUrl("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query", "GET", b);
            Log.i("MyResult", myResult);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Facebook fb; so the above code facebookManager.mFacebook.getAccessToken() will be facebookManager.fb.getAccessToken()  ??   What is facebookManager I am getting an error.

Comment: Facebookmanager is a class which facebook class instantiated. Mfacebook is static variable

Comment: Please check your device internet connection.

Comment: I did that I have tried both on wifi and 3G device HtC Incredible S.

Comment: Sorry but i dont have any idea, why it didnt work on device. But my answer is working when i try.

Comment: I checked my code and this I guess is the problem:fb.authorize(MainActivity.this,new String[] {"email","user_birthday","read_stream", "offline_access" }, new Facebook.DialogListener() { }                       I guess it should be mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() { }  What do you think?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20119/discussion-between-talhakosen-and-jason-wood)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add null point exception in your code

```
try {
                            json = Util.parseJson(fb.request("me"));
                        } catch (NullPointException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```